Is there a way to recover deleted Local History entries in VS Code?
VS Studio Code has the following setting:
Workbench > Local History: Max File Entries


Controls the maximum number of local file history entries per file. When the number of local file history entries exceeds this number for a file, the oldest entries will be discarded. (Default is 50)

I was unaware of this and exceeded the max file entry so my previous history entries have been discarded. Is there anyway to recover these entries?
I know this is kind of a niche ask but I need to be able to show proof of my code's progress (using timeline as it stores previous versions + timestamp) for credit in my class in order to get credit for this summative assignment...
I have already tried looking through my recycling bin on my computer to find these entries, however I was unsuccessful. However a friend said it could be in a hidden directory somewhere (not sure what that means). Any help with my problem would be greatly appreciated.

No. They're gone. They get deleted and then the disk space is reused by subsequent files.


However a friend said it could be in a hidden directory somewhere

What's backing your friend's words? Tracing the code paths which reach a call to WorkingCopyHistoryModel.cleanUpEntries(), I don't think so. Clean up (which deletes files from disk) is performed pretty consistently for all mutating operations.
If you didn't use any other form of backup (Ex. version control software, manual file copies, or OS-level backups), I don't think you have anything else other than the complicated data recovery stuff I link to at the end of my answer post to a similar question.


I need to be able to show proof of my code's progress (using timeline as it stores previous versions + timestamp) for credit in my class in order to get credit for this summative assignment...

Rant: Any "facts" concerning proof of work which never reached your prof on an immediate routine basis  and lived their entire life on the student side can be falsified. This is an unreliable method, and I'm surprised/disappointed your prof is using it.
